# Is it possible to remove keyboard access in a standard JavaScript prompt/confirm pop-up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

Is it possible to stop keyboard access on a standard JavaScript prompt or confirm pop-up box? For example, if I have some like the following:

```
var name = prompt("Enter your name:");
```

By default, there are the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons, which can be keyboard/tab accessible. Is there a way to remove the keyboard control? I am looking only for a simple solution (e.g. may be an existing jQuery/JavaScript function etc?).

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: you can create a custom popup, and bind the keyboard events to return false

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? That would be very annoying for  people who simply prefer to submit by keyboard, who may just assume your site is broken when it does not work. For those who cannot use a mouse very well it would be even worse, as this is an accessibility feature provided by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is provided natively by the browser -- when displaying a true system modal (such as with prompt() or alert()), you have no access to events.

As RooVM's comment above says, a possible solution is to implement your own, on-page modal using JS and HTML. That way, since it's part of the page, you can hijack the events all you want.

For an example, or perhaps an easy component to implement, check out [Bootstrap's modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom modal. By doing so you won't have to unbind those events because they won't be bound in the first place.